# Material icon_value for UIList

Tags: python

Is there a way to get the icon_value of a material for use with a UIList? When using a UIList with bpy.data.materials as the target list, the icon value seems to be passed to the draw function, but I'm not seeing a way to get the integer ID myself from bpy.data.materials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the icon value from the [UILayout classmethod icon](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.icon)

Example using the simple panel template.

```
import bpy

class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        obj = context.object
        mat = obj.active_material
        layout.label(mat.name, icon_value = layout.icon(mat))

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```